# Mongoose update subdocument with save is not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to update an object in an array.

My code:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {

  var givenProject = req.body;
  var query = mongoose.model('cv').findOne({alias: req.params.alias});

  query.exec(function(err, cv){
    if(err){
      res.status(400).send({message: 'Could not find cv with alias: ' + req.params.alias, err: err})
     }
    var doc = cv.projects.id(req.params.id);
    doc.langTitles = givenProject.langTitles;
    doc.langDescriptions = givenProject.langDescriptions;
    doc.save(function(err){
      if(err){
        res.status(400).send({message: 'Could not update project', err: err});
        return;
      }
      res.status(200).send();
    });
  });
};
```

No error is given. `var doc` is found and the posted data have the same data structure as `doc` and it differs from the original.

The doc is not updated. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is doc after the line `var doc = cv.projects.id(req.params.id);`? What is `cv.projects`? Is `cv.projects.id` a function?

Comment: Its a built in function in mongoose to find subdocuments. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Mongoose [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html):

> Sub-documents enjoy all the same features as normal documents. The
>   only difference is that t**hey are not saved individually**, **they are**
>   **saved whenever their top-level parent document is saved**.

Therefore try replacing

```
doc.save(function(err) ...
```

with

```
cv.save(function(err) ...
```